# F# and P/Invoke using out parameters

Tags: f#, interop, pinvoke

I'm working with a third party API, and trying to translate the following C# code into F#:

```
[DllImport("libfsdk.so", EntryPoint = "FSDK_FeedFrame", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int FSDK_FeedFrame_Old(int Tracker, long CameraIdx, int Image, ref long FaceCount, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] long[] IDs, long MaxSizeInBytes);
public static int FeedFrame(int Tracker, long CameraIdx, int Image, ref long FaceCount, out long[] IDs, long MaxSizeInBytes)
{
    IDs = new long[MaxSizeInBytes/8];
    return FSDK_FeedFrame_Old(Tracker, CameraIdx, Image, ref FaceCount, IDs, MaxSizeInBytes);
}
```

My attempt so far is this:

```
[<DllImport("libfsdk.so", EntryPoint = "FSDK_FeedFrame", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int private FSDK_FeedFrame(int Tracker, int64 CameraIdx, int Image, int64& FaceCount, [<Out; MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)>] int64[] IDs, int64 MaxSizeInBytes);
let FeedFrame(Tracker: int, CameraIdx: int64, Image: int, faceCount: int64 byref, [<Out>] IDs: int64[] byref, MaxSizeInBytes: int64) =
    let ids = Array.create (int MaxSizeInBytes) 0L
    let mutable fc = 0L
    let res = FSDK_FeedFrame(Tracker, CameraIdx, Image, &fc, ids, MaxSizeInBytes)
    res
```

I have tried variants of `byref` in the argument list, but the result code always indicates an invalid argument. Is there any special variant I need so that I can use this P/Invoke method?